# C#, in List<>.ConvertAll method using lambda expression, how to make a filter when the object is null?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

```
string[] myTargetArray=myClassList.ConvertAll<string>(xi=>xi.objStr).ToArray();
```

Here, myClassList is a List, and for some reason, the items in the List might be null.

How to achieve this using lambda expression: when the object is not null, return the objStr, if it's null, return an empty string "" ?

Comment: `xi=>xi.objStr ?? ""`

Comment: @KhanhTO I believe `xi` is the object that could potentially be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it

```
string[] myTargetArray=myClassList.ConvertAll<string>(xi => xi==null ? string.Empty : xi.objStr).ToArray();
```

Comment: In C#6, `xi?.objStr ?? string.Empty`.

Answer (score 1):

When converting lists of Classes, an example of a `First` list type into a list of `Second` type:

```
class First
{
    int id;
    string description;
    DateTime creation;
}

class Second
{
    int id;
    string fullInfo;
}

// more code, not interesting

List<First> firstList = new List();
List<Second> secondList;
firstList.AddRange(fictionalData);
secondList = firstList.ConvertAll(item => new Second {
    id = item.id,
    fullInfo = item.description + " " + item.creation.Year"
} );
```