# Java setCellValueFactory lambda expression when null is possible

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I have the following line of code to set up a column in JavaFX:

`branchActionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getAction().getTextProperty());`

This typically works fine.  However, sometimes `getAction()` returns null (and that can be normal behavior).  In that case I'd like to just display the empty string "".  How could I do that?

I've tried:

`branchActionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> (cd.getValue().getAction() == null) ? new SimpleStringProperty("") : cd.getValue().getAction().getTextProperty());`

While this displays the initial value of the property in the TableView, any subsequent changes made to the property are not reflected in the TableView.  I believe this is because I am creating a new property inside the lambda expression.

If I go back to the line `branchActionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getAction().getTextProperty());` then the TableView responds appropriately whenever the property changes.  This is the behavior that I want.  I just also want it to handle the case when `getAction()` returns null.

Here is a similar question, but it's for C# and it's not related to a CellValueFactory: [C#, in List<>.ConvertAll method using lambda expression, how to make a filter when the object is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184843/c-in-list-convertall-method-using-lambda-expression-how-to-make-a-filter-wh)

Comment: Even though it is a lambda function, it can still have a multi-statement body. You can do `cd -> { if(cd.getValue().getAction() == null) trueStatement; else falseStatement; }` If you had not shown your ternary operator attempt, I would have posted this as an answer, instead it's a comment since it's basically equivalent, but it should be more readable if you split the code out into a few lines with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what all you do with `getAction()`, but you may be able to just initialize the `SimpleStringProperty` in that class to be `("")` instead of `()`, it may change/break some other code though.

Comment: The version you show with the ternary expression should work (though if your cell is editable you may need to treat that case separately in an `onEditCommit` handler). If it's not working, something else in your code is (presumably) wrong, somewhere.

Comment: `Optional` is handy when you have a string of getters, any of which might return null, because any `map` call that returns null changes the `Optional` to the empty state.  You might try an expression like `Optional.ofNullable(cd).map(CDClass::getValue).map(CDValueClass::getAction).map(ActionClass::getTextProperty).orElse("")` If any nulls pop up, you get the default `""` value.

Comment: Both my ternary expression solution as well as the solution using an Optional will compile and correctly display the starting value of the StringProperty.  The problem now is the following: When the StringProperty changes, the Table is not updated to reflect the change.

Comment: @James_D You were right, there was a problem elsewhere in my code.  The ternary expression I have does work, at least for setting things up initially (i.e., the TableView column displays the correct text).  But if there are any changes made to that StringProperty, those changes are not reflected in the TableView.  (FYI the cells in my table are not editable)

Comment: @HypnicJerk I am initializing the `SimpleStringProperty` inside `Action` to be `""`.  But the problem is: what do I do if `getAction()` returns null?  In that case, there is no `Action` object and therefore there is no `SimpleStringProperty` for me to return or initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use optional

```
branchActionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(cd.getValue().getAction())
        .map(action -> action.getTextProperty())
        .orElseGet(() -> new SimpleStringProperty(""))
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this and it does display the value of the StringProperty initially.  However, if the value of the StringProperty changes, the TableView is not updated.

Comment: I think maybe the reason for this is because a new SimpleStringProperty is being created inside the CellValueFactory.  So in a sense we are dealing with two StringProperties, the one returned by getTextProperty() and the one returned by new SimpleStringProperty().  So the TableView cannot track whether the property has changed since it is not changing but rather being replaced...?

Comment: As another way of saying it: if I leave the line of code as `branchActionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getAction().getTextProperty());` then the TableView is updated appropriately whenever the property changes its value.  This is the behavior I want.  I just also need it to also somehow handle the case where `getAction()` returns null.